# disk [users] not configured, please add a disk config in `config/filesystems.php`

Tags: php, laravel, config, disk

- PHP version   PHP/8.1.10
- Laravel version   9.28.0

While working on a Laravel-admin backend, I tried creating a new user (basically inserting data into admin_user table in the database)

working on my windows computer, I encountered the error:

> disk [users] not configured, please add a disk config in `config/filesystems.php`.

I revisited the Laravel docs and these are the things I did to solve the problem:

1. Opened the config/admin.php and added:

```
'disk' => 'users',

         // Image and file upload path under the disk above.
         'directory' => [
            'image' => 'images',
            'file'  => 'files',
        ],
```

2. Then opened the config/filesystems.php and added:

```
'users' => [ 
            'driver' => 'local', 
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
             ]
```

3. Closed my git bash and reopened it, ran:

```
php artisan serve
```

4. Accessed the page for creating a user and the error was solved..

**Do you know any other way this could be solved?**

Comment: In `filesystem.php`, is it `'disks' => ['users' => [...]]` or just `'users' => [...]`? The 1st one will work, but the 2nd will not. [Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9BY5.png)

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom `disk` you must configure it first. To configure a `disk`, follow the following steps:

1. Open `filesystems.php` file, under `config` directory, in your preferred text editor or IDE.
2. Look for the key named `disks`. The array under `disks` is where you configure your disks. Laravel already provides some `disks` out of the box (I recommend not messing with them unless you know what you are doing).
3. Add your new disk configuration, something like:

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/users'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/users',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

> **Note:** The above example assumes you have already executed `php artisan storage:link` command in order to create a symbolic link that allows the files in `storage/app/public` to be accessible from outside.

4. Save the file and now you can use that new `disk` like below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// initialize a new disk using the `users` disk config
$disk = Storage::disk('users');

// perform actions under that disk
$disk->delete('sub/folder/file.ext');
```

Also, it is important to note that you are not limited to have disks under the `storage` folder, you can actually have disks under the `public` folder:

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('/users'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/users',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

> Note that the function `public_path` is used instead of `storage_path`. Also the command `php artisan storage:link` is not needed when your disks are under the `public` folder.

> Learn more about **[File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#configuration)** in Laravel.